# ImageView no me carga con su ruta android studio

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, android-imageview

Desde mi aplicación accedo a la galería para seleccionar una imagen, luego de seleccionarla en la base de datos guardo la ruta de dicha imagen, pero luego para cargarla en un imageview no me la carga con la ruta guardada y es que note el siguiente problema, la ruta que me guarda no es la que dice que tiene el archivo realmente.

```
public class Agregar_foto extends AppCompatActivity{
ImageView imagen;
Uri path;
String numero;
BDHelper mDbHelper;
Button guardar;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.foto);
    imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.agfoto);
    guardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnguardarfoto);
    Bundle mibundle;
    mibundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    numero = mibundle.getString("numero_telefonito");
    mDbHelper = new BDHelper(this,"bd_vinculator",null,1);

}
public void irafoto(View v){
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/");
    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione la aplicación"),10);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        path = data.getData();
        Toast.makeText(this,path.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        imagen.setImageURI(path);
    }
}
public void guardarFoto(View v){
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (path.toString().isEmpty()) {

        }else{
            String sql = "Update CONTACTO set " + Utilidades.Campo_foto + " = ' " + path.toString() +"'" ;
            try{
                db.execSQL(sql);
                db.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                finish();
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        finish();
    }


    finish();
}
@Override

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    buscar();
}
private void buscar() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT foto FROM " + Utilidades.Tabla_Contacto + " WHERE " + Utilidades.Campo_telef + " = '"+numero + "'",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Toast.makeText(this,cursor.getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try{
        imagen.setImageURI(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(0)));

    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,e+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    db.close();
}
```

}

La ruta que me guarda en la base de datos (local sqlite) es así: 
**content://media/external/images/media/39**
Y la ruta que me dice dentro del celular es:
**/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/454980.png**
Si pongo en el imagen.setImageUri la segunda ruta me carga la imagen sin problemas, pero si pongo la primera no lo hace, como podría obtener la segunda ruta en código?.